# @include in blade template overrides rest of content in section

Tags: laravel, include, overriding, laravel-blade

I have a laravel site using blade templates.
My template fills in some content of the basic layout and uses a `@include()` while doing this:

```
@section('content')
    [some html and other @-code]

    @include('form-text')

@stop
```

The basic layout requires the content section by `@yield('content')`, which works for everthing else so far.
But when loading the page i only get only the content of the include, not the trailing resulting code. As soon as I comment the include out, I get the results of the trailing code.

Does the `@include` override the other code?
Is there an alternative to `@include` or do I miss something else like a `@parent`-like command?

thx in advance,
  nx

Comment: Are you saying your `[some html and other @-code]` is gone when you use the `@include`?

Comment: Yes - the code itself is not gone, but the output is simply not shown, and not in the received webpage.

Comment: Never used the sub-views before, but maybe you can try defining `@section` in your subviews and/or `@parent`. There is lack of documentation for subviews currently, so all the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I simply used a second section in my template, that is directly after the content-section (called it the 'form'-section) to include the subview (a form behind the content). Other templates using the layout do not need to know about this, and if left untouched this section is empty.

Tried to find a difference between `@yield` and `@section … @show` to mark where to inject the later content, but I could not find a solution.